# is return main(); a valid syntax?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I found some interesting code lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hi there");
    return main();
}
```

It compiles OK (VS2013) and ends up in stackoverflow error because of the  recursive call to `main()`. I didn't know that the `return` statement accepts any parameter that can be evaluated to the expected return data type, in this example even `int main()`.

Standard C or Microsoft-ish behaviour?

Comment: Read about functions. Hint: `main()` is a function.

Comment: What's so impressive about this example for you? It's just a regular recursive call.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves - maybe because it is the simplest recursive call you could write?

Comment: As in most cases where you encounter recursion, it is just stupid over-engineering and generally bad-practice. This very example will just eat up all the stack and then crash and burn. Impressive indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I didn't know that the return statement accepts any parameter that can be evaluated to the expected return data type,*

Well, a `return` statement can have an expression.

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter 6.8.6.4, *The `return` statement*.

> If a `return` statement with an expression is executed, the value of the expression is returned to the caller as the value of the function call expression.

so, in case of `return main();`, the `main();` function call is the *expression*.

And regarding the behaviour of `return main();`, this behaves like a normal recursive function, the exception being an infinite recursion in this case.

> *Standard `C` or Microsoft-ish behaviour?*

As long as `C` standard is considered, it **does not impose any restriction** upon calling `main()` recursively.

However, FWIW, AFAIK, in `C++`, it is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

In C, `main` can be called like any other function for example in a return statement like in your program.

Calling `main` recursively is allowed as it is with other functions, there is no special restriction:

> (C11, 6.5.2.2p11) "Recursive function calls shall be permitted, both directly and indirectly through any chain of other functions."

In C++, it is not allowed to call `main`, so the function cannot be called in a return statement.

> (C++11, 3.6.1p3) "The function main shall not be used within a program"